# SublimeClang on Sublime text 3

Tags: clang, sublimetext3

Has anyone been able to use clang on ST3... I am getting various errors... I made some changes in the code to support python3 but still i am unable to use.

After the changes i have come to a stage where i am getting the following error

```
 File "C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeClan\clang          
 \cindex.py", line 86, in get_cindex_library  return cdll.LoadLibrary('libclang.dll')
 File "X/ctypes/__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
  File "X/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
  OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Comment: @Athanase I saw that you got it working .. can you please help???

Comment: Sorry @Lonewolf, I just saw your post. Is it working for you now ?

Comment: @Athanase Some time since i last used.. but was working then.. Thank you for the reply...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone trying to get sublimeclang working in ST3... please follow my post in [Sublime Text Forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=13099)

Also check the following link for certain errors arising [ST3 Clang Error](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=13150)